# Problem getting data out of an array

Tags: php, arrays

```
array(10) {
   "name" => "samn" (10)
   "email" => "sam@gmail.com" (20)
   "title" => "hello world" (8)
   "postcode" => "55555" (5)
   "telephone" => "123123123" (9)
   "category_id" => FALSE
}
```

how to foreach selected data?
i mean something like this

```
foreach($data as $row)
{
   echo $row->email;
   echo $row->title;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach($data as $row)
{
   echo $row['email'];
   echo $row['title'];
}
```

You should go through an intro tutorial to PHP or something.

Comment: i'm getting the error

Arrayssa
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Uninitialized string offset: 0

Filename: ai/ai.php

Line Number: 84
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Uninitialized string offset: 0

Filename: form.php

Line Number: 84
1p

Comment: are you sure you're initializing `$data` properly?

Answer (score 2):

Reference associative array elements using array notation. Like this:

```
foreach($data as $row)
{
   echo $row["email"];
   echo $row["title"];
}
```

The `->` operator is object notation and not applicable in your example.